# i want toggle menu appear from @468 to @1000px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

i want the mobile menu appear from @media468px to @media1000px, it's possible? i try to change some value, but not working. i don't find the right row to modify in the "bootstrap.css" classic file. i would to post the entire file, but is too long.

thank's to all for the attention and excuse for my bad english.

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar 
{background-color: #bc2132;
box-shadow: 1px 1px #000;}

.navbar-toggle 
{background-color: transparent;
border: none;}

.navbar-toggle:hover 
{background-color: transparent! important;}

.navbar-toggle:focus 
{background-color: transparent! important;}

.navbar-default
{background-color: #222;
border-color: transparent;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a
{color: #FFF;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover
{color: #bc2132;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover
{background-color: yellow;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover
{background-color: blue;}

.dropdown-menu>li>a
{color: green;}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover
{background-color: brown;
color: violet;}

.navbar-brand>li>a:hover
{color: white;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
.collapsing, .in {background: #222;}
.collapsing ul li a, .in ul li a {color: #fff!important; float: left;}
.collapsing ul li a:hover, .in ul li a:hover {color: #fff !important; background-color: #E1332D;}
}


.navbar {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
}

.navbar.scrolled {
    background: rgb(68, 68, 68); //IE
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78); //NON-IE
}

li 
{text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries

By example:
`@media screen and (min-width: 468px) and (max-width: 1000px) { … }`

If you want to override bootstrap css it's better to put that rule (above) after bootstrap.css loads. Check in dev mode if your rule gets overriden by bootstrap.

Docs at [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width)

Comment: i edit my first comment, where i post "@media screen and (min-width: 468px) and (max-width: 1000px)" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you should use **media queries**. Add this to your .css file:

```
    @media (max-width:1000px) and (min-width:468px) {
        .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar 
        {background-color: #bc2132;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px #000;}

        .navbar-toggle 
        {background-color: transparent;
        border: none;}

        .navbar-toggle:hover 
        {background-color: transparent! important;}

        .navbar-toggle:focus 
        {background-color: transparent! important;}

        .navbar-default
        {background-color: #222;
        border-color: transparent;}

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a
        {color: #FFF;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;}

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover
        {color: #bc2132;}

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover
        {background-color: yellow;}

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover
        {background-color: blue;}

        .dropdown-menu>li>a
        {color: green;}

        .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover
        {background-color: brown;
        color: violet;}

        .navbar-brand>li>a:hover
        {color: white;}    

        .navbar {
            -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
        }

        .navbar.scrolled {
            background: rgb(68, 68, 68); //IE
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78); //NON-IE
        }

        li 
        {text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;}
        }​
    }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
        .collapsing, .in {background: #222;}
        .collapsing ul li a, .in ul li a {color: #fff!important; float: left;}
        .collapsing ul li a:hover, .in ul li a:hover {color: #fff !important; background-color: #E1332D;}
        }
```

Comment: i edit my first comment, where i post "@media (max-width:1000px) and (min-width:468px)" ?

Comment: in your `style.css` file or whatever you call it, preferably at the bottom of the document, so you don't overwrite it accidentally.

Comment: Wait, the code you provided is what you want to  be applied for screens sized **between 468px and 1000px** ?

Comment: yes, this is a part of my style.css. in this part, i modified the style of the menu desktop and mobile.

Comment: sorry, but not work. your code change only my color of navbar when i enlarge the window.